# How to configure GITLAB for code view only?

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, docker-container

How to configure the git repo of the server on gitlab so that it can be only used for code view, and the server's git will handle rest.

I mean I will do code pull-push using smartgit (any git client), but I need to track and observe the changes of code on GITLAB.

***Note:***
GITLAB is running as a container on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a project in `GITLAB`, go to `git` directory on server then execute the commands for already existing repositories.

Then you can create **hook** named as `post-receive` and add `git push origin -all` to it. In this way you can use existing git for usual functioning and `GITLAB` for code view.

Note: you can replace origin by your `git repo` URL.